# How to add between two numbers +1 ticket

Tags: php, loops, while-loop

i have database list for users and user's coupons and i want to add +1 ticket per coupon if bigger than two between numbers.

For example:

```
100 between 200 = 1 ticket
200 between 300 = 2 ticket
300 between 400 = 3 ticket
.......
.......
1200 between 1300 = 12 ticket
```

i put photo for example:

[image]

My Code is :

```
$q=$db->query("SELECT DISTINCT client_id  FROM kuponlar ORDER BY client_id LIMIT 20");
 foreach($q as $cat){
    echo '<li id="'.$cat['client_id'].'" class="files">';  
    echo 'User ID: <a href="'.$cat['client_id'].'">'.$cat['client_id'].'</a>'; 
    echo '<ul class="sub-menu">';
    $linkq=$db->query("SELECT * FROM kuponlar WHERE client_id='" . $cat['client_id'] . "'"); 
    foreach($linkq as $link){
       echo '<li>Coupon ID: <a href="#">'.$link['kuponid'].'</a> - Coupon Price: '.$link['yatirimi'].' ₺  / Won Ticket: '.substr($link['yatirimi'], 0, 1).' </li>';
    }
    echo '</ul></li>';
}
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Let's see some code :-)

Comment: i edit question. now you can check it again.

Comment: How is this code not working? Judging by the example at the top of your question, this works as expected, doesn't it?

Comment: @IsmailAltunören If i understand well your problem, if you have a thing like it's :50 between 55= 3 tickets
If s/o have a coupon of 54 he will have 3 tickets. Or it's only by hundreds steps ?

Comment: @Qirel depends of what he wants, this workaround will work only if the"steps" are hundreds. I think he wants to customises each step.

Comment: its working. but only showing 999 and less counts. after 999 showing again 1 ticket for 1000 price. if 1000 price must to show 10 ticket. 100 and 199 = 1 ticket 200 and 299 = 2 ticket like this.

Comment: Yes @Nico every hundreds i must to give +1 ticket for 100 = 1 for 200 = 2 for 1500 = 15 ticket.

Comment: So if the number is 12 000, you want `120` as a result? Basically divide by 100?

Comment: Yes @Qirel this is perfect comment. i mean like this. but sorry for my english. Could you please help for this?

Comment: @IsmailAltunören I posted an answer (as did others). Have a look through them below. :-)

Comment: Thank you @Qirel good solution. Regards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this using `floor()`:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.floor.php

> floor — Round fractions down

So this should do the trick: `floor($link['yatirimi'] / 100)`

Use that in place of your `substr`.

Answer (score 3):

As discussed in the comments;

> - So if the number is 12 000, you want 120 as a result? Basically divide by 100? – Qirel
> - Yes @Qirel this is perfect comment. i mean like this. (...) – Ismail Altunören

So put simply, you want to divide the number by 100. You must then floor it, to get a full integer and get rid of any decimal points.

```
floor($link['yatirimi']/100);
```

You would replace that with your `substr()`, making the full line

```
echo '<li>Coupon ID: <a href="#">'.$link['kuponid'].'</a> - Coupon Price: '.$link['yatirimi'].' ₺  / Won Ticket: '.floor($link['yatirimi']/100).' </li>';
```

- [`floor()` docs](http://php.net/floor)

Answer (score 0):

you can user this: `$wonTicketsCount = round(($link['yatirimi'] / 100 ) - 0.5);` instead `substr($link['yatirimi'], 0, 1)`.

Answer (score 0):

Refering to your comments if you only use hundreds steps :

Modify this line :

```
substr($link['yatirimi'], 0, 1)
```

This line will always take the first number.

By : this one
This will take all numbers excepts the two lasts.

```
substr($link['yatirimi'],0,-2);
```

By keeping the substr, it will not work for number between 0-100,
It's better to use @Qirel's Anwser.